# A classic symbol sequence

Tags: pattern, symbols

*I saw a similar puzzle in a book long time ago.*

---

[image]

> What will be the next symbol?

Comment: As featured on [The Simpsons!](http://i.imgur.com/SMqQmyT.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The next image** in the sequence should be this symbol:

> [image]

Because:

> These are numbers drawn with a reflection of the number in front of the digit.  `1,2,3…`! And as you see ending number is `5`, So the next one will be **`6`**.

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> [image: Mirror6]

Reason:

> Each image is a digit with its horizontal mirror image on it's left side